# What is the cmd script equivalent for C scanf() function?

Tags: c, windows, cmd

I'm developing a `cmd` script to automate a function, however, it depends on one interaction with the user. The user will need to pass one drive letter(C, D, E, F..) to the script and thats all, the script will do all it's tasks. However, I can't find a solution on the internet... If you don't understand what I am mean, what I need is the `cmd` equivalent to the C `scanf` or gets functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

```
set /p dl=Enter a drive: 
echo user entered %dl%
```

or it will be n `$1` if you pass it as an argument.